# Video editing software that automatically performs search-and-replace

Tags: video, editing, audio

My employer owns a number of video recordings that discuss a company product. Many of those videos were created using Camtasia, a commercial video editing software product. The video recordings repeatedly mention terminology associated with a given company product. That terminology is used both in the audio and video portions of those video recordings. When that terminology is used in the video portion of the video recordings, the related text was often entered into a Powerpoint slide deck that was then incorporated into the video recording.

A small amount of updated terminology needs to be incorporated into both the audio and video portions of those video recordings. I'd like to see whether there are one or more tools that we might use to automatically perform a search-and-replace operation for the updated terminology.

Ideally:

- Text shown in the video would be updated using the same font and other formatting used in the original text to display the updated terminology.
- Audio would be updated using a credible simulation of the original speaker's voice reading the updated terminology.

Whatever degree of automation we can use to accomplish this task would be worth our consideration.

I'd like to thank the StackExchange Video Production community for your anticipated assistance in answering this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While each of these things you want are technically possible right now, in reality you would need to create the tooling for your needs. There is no off the shelf product to do this, there is no way to shortcut the effort you need to make.

tl;dr - you're going to need to re-record the audio, and recreate the powerpoint slides and edit them into your video.